# SQL Developer code formatting

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I have just cut 'n' paste some SQL code into SQL developer (4.0.2.15). I have a right margin set and selected CTRL+F7 to format it. However I have two problems

1. The code is wider that the right margin I have set
2. The keywords are in capitals and the coding standard here is lowercase.

I have been unable to find how to change this or is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a google search for the phrase "sql developer code formatting", and the first hit was this:

http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/03/how-to-make-your-code-look-like-steven-feuersteins-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Have a read through that blog post from Jeff Smith, product manager for SQL Developer.  That should explain what you need to do.

Edited to add picture of the relevant options.
[image: pic of tree showing relevant options]

Comment: I read that page. The options for me is to import/export the settings as an XML file - Not the dialog as displayed. I must be using an older version.

Comment: @EdHeal: looks like you're not on the right "branch" in the preferences menu. The import/export options are on the "Database/SQL Formatter" node, you need to go one deeper "Database/SQL Formatter/Oracle Formatting", then click "edit" next to the profile dropdown on that screen. This works on 4.0.2.

Answer (score 3):

Has actually moved in v17.4

Can be found in:
Oracle SQL Developer -> Preferences... 
-> Code Editor -> Format

and Optionally 
-> Advanced Format -> Custom Format